# Load vendor package class in prestashop module. (Prestashop 1.6)

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I have a similar issue. I am using Prestashop 1.6 version and I need to implement this package in my module.

Link - https://github.com/hotelbeds-sdk/hotel-api-sdk-php

I am getting data perfectly in Core PHP separate file

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// require('../../config/config.inc.php');

use hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\HotelApiClient;
use hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\model\Destination;
use hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\model\Occupancy;
use hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\model\Pax;
use hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\model\Rate;
use hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\model\Stay;
use hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\types\ApiVersion;
use hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\types\ApiVersions;
use hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\messages\AvailabilityRS;

class techsoftdk extends Module
{

public function getContent()
    {

        $reader = new Zend\Config\Reader\Ini();
        $config = $reader->fromFile(__DIR__.'/HotelApiClient.ini');
        $cfgApi = $config["apiclient"];

       /* echo "<pre>";
       print_r($cfgApi);die;*/

        $apiClient = new HotelApiClient($cfgApi["url"],  // getting error here, class is not loading
        $cfgApi["apikey"],
        $cfgApi["sharedsecret"],                             
        new ApiVersion(ApiVersions::V1_0),
        $cfgApi["timeout"]);
        $rqData = new \hotelbeds\hotel_api_sdk\helpers\Availability();

        echo '<pre>'; 
        print_r($rqData);die;


  return 'test';    /*$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
        $data = '<h1>testing developer</h1> </br> <input type="text" name="test">';

        return $data;*/
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me how to use it.